# array length in node.js

Tags: arrays, angularjs, node.js

I have form object returned from angular js to node js which looks like this in console,

for two files,

```
filenames : [object Object],[object Object] # filenames object for two files
length: 2 # used object.length
```

for one file,

```
filenames : [object Object] # filenames object for one file
length: undefined # used object.length
```

I am new to Node js, Can anybody please explain me why like this?

**Edited**

ProfileController.js(client side)

```
var fd = new FormData()
var filenames = $scope.postTextOrImageParams.imageUrl;
for( var i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++ ) {
     fd.append("imageData",$scope.postTextOrImageParams.imageUrl[i]);  
}
```

user.js(server side)

```
var filenames = req.files.imageData;
console.log(typeof filenames);   //-> object
console.log('filenames : '+filenames);
console.log('length: '+filenames.length); 


 function uploader(i) {

 if( i < filenames.length ) { 
         utils.saveMediaPic(filenames[i],function(error,savedImagePath){
      if( error ) {
          console.log('error: '+error)
       }
      else {
          console.log("SAVED IMAGE ====>"+savedImagePath);
          post.content.imageUrl.push(savedImagePath);

          uploader(i+1)
          }
    });
}
```

Comment: could you add a bigger part of your code?.

Comment: Could you add the objects or an example object you are using?

Comment: are you sure that in the second case it is actually an Array. Use the Array.isArray() method to check it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: @cs04iz1, Please see the code, I have edited

Comment: @B3rn475, Thanks, It is returning `false` for single file object, returning `true` for multiple file objects. Do u have an idea why like this?

Comment: If you send just one parameter in the request body it is converted to a single value. If you add more than one value to the body of the request it is converted to array. It is part of the deconding procedure.

Comment: If you want it to be Always an array use the extended version of body-parser and call the parameter imageData[] in this way it is Always an array

Comment: @B3rn475, I have used `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` and Could you please show me, how can I write this, I don't think this should be right way, `var filenames = req.files.imageData[];`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs#readme in parsing arrays you can see that if you user .append("imageData[]", ....) on the client the req.files.imageData should be an array.

Comment: @B3rn475, Thanks a lot, it solved my problem, Please write it in answer, wil accept and wil be useful to others too :)

Comment: @pydev I've done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the body you have more than one parameter with the same name the bodyParser will generate an array. You problem is that when you have only one perameter it is not so.

In order to force so, you can use the bodyParser in the extended version.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

and call the parameter with the squared brackets imageData[]

```
fd.append("imageData[]",...
```

As you can find in the documentation http://npmjs.com/package/qs#readme

This will trigger the extended parser to always return an array.